# Cannot add comment to SQL db in python Flask app

Tags: python, sql, forms, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I am new to programming and have setup a small website with a comments section on pythonanywhere.com, relaying heavily on their tutorial. But when I post a comment in the form, the comment is not added to the database and for some reason the program redirects me to the index page (the intention is to redirect to stay on the same page)

Any suggestions as to what I might be doing wrong would be greatly appreciated!

The pyhthon code:

```
import random
from flask import Flask, request, session, redirect, url_for, render_template, flash
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from werkzeug.routing import RequestRedirect

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["DEBUG"] = True

SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = "mysql+mysqlconnector://{username}:{password}@{hostname}/{databasename}".format(
    username="username",
    password="password",
    hostname="hostname",
    databasename="majaokholm$majaokholm",
)
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_POOL_RECYCLE"] = 299

db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class Comment(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = "comments"

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    content = db.Column(db.String(4096))

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template("index_page.html")

@app.route('/post', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def post():
    if request.method == "GET":
        return render_template("post_page.html", comments=Comment.query.all())
    comment = Comment(content=request.form["contents"])
    db.session.add(comment)
    db.session.commit()
    return redirect(url_for('post'))
```

and the form from the HTML template:

```
<form action="." method="POST">
<textarea class="form-control" name="contents" placeholder="Enter a 
comment"></textarea>
<input type="submit" value="Post comment">
                </form>
```

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: PS. Be careful with credentials...

Comment: Hey!!! You're revealing your database credentials. I can see your username & password.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, the `action="."` in the form actually points to the root of the current directory, which for `/post` happens to be just `/` and thus points to the `index`.

It's always better to use `action="{{ url_for('your_target_view') }}"` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 0):

get rid of `action="."`, you can use `action=""`